# Issues with logical not operator (!) adding class to wrong button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button, negation

I have a list of buttons. When one of them is clicked, I'm looking to give all other buttons a class of `not-selected`, which changes the colour of their text to grey and makes pointer-events:none

I'm using a click handler, not sure if my use of an exclamation `!` is correct because it keeps adding that class to the button I just clicked as opposed to all the buttons that weren't clicked.

```
$(".btn--list").on("click", function(){
    !($(this).addClass("not-selected"));
)};
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><h2>Filters</h2></li>
    <li class="filter--all"><button class="btn--list btn--all is-selected">Select All</button></li>

    <li><h2>Decade</h2></li>
    <li><button class="btn--list btn--1960">1960s</button></li>
    <li><button class="btn--list btn--1970">1970s</button></li>
    <li><button class="btn--list btn--1980">1980s</button></li>
    <li><button class="btn--list btn--1990">1990s</button></li>
    <li><button class="btn--list btn--2000">2000s</button></li>
    <li><button class="btn--list btn--2010">2010s</button></li>

    <li><h2>Position</h2></li>
    <li><button class="btn--list btn--goalie">Goalie</button></li>
    <li><button class="btn--list btn--defencemen">Defenceman</button></li>
    <li><button class="btn--list btn--forward">Forward</button></li>

    <li><h2>Other</h2></li>
    <li><button class="btn--list btn--name">First Name</button></li>
    <li><button class="btn--list btn--hometown">Hometown</button></li>
    <li><button class="btn--list btn--gamesp">Games Played</button></li>
    <li class="not--goalie not--goals"><button class="btn--list btn--goals">Goals</button></li>
    <li class="not--goalie not-assists"><button class="btn--list btn--assists">Assists</button></li>
    <li class="not--goalie not-points"><button class="btn--list btn--points">Points</button></li>
    <li class="not--goalie not-penalty"><button class="btn--list btn--penalty">Penalty Minutes</button></li>
    <li><button class="btn--list btn--goalsagainst">Goals Against <span class="is-highlighted">*</span></button></li>
    <li><button class="btn--list btn--savepercent">Save Percentage <span class="is-highlighted">*</span></button></li>
    <li><button class="btn--list btn--shutouts">Shutouts <span class="is-highlighted">*</span></button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Let's think about `!($(this).addClass("not-selected"));` for a moment, how would the JavaScript engine run that? Skipping some pedantic details, first it calls `$(this)`, then it calls `addClass("not-selected")` on the result, then it takes that result and inverts it with `!`, and then it throws away that value because it's not being used for anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your use of the `!` operator on a jQuery object is invalid. To achieve what you require, you could select all `.btn--list` elements and exclude the current one with `.not(this)`. Try this:

```js
$(".btn--list").on("click", function() {
    $(".btn--list").not(this).addClass("not-selected");
});
```

```css
/* For demo purposes... */
.not-selected {
  background-color: #c00;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <h2>Filters</h2>
  </li>
  <li class="filter--all">
    <button class="btn--list btn--all is-selected">Select All</button>
  </li>

  <li>
    <h2>Decade</h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn--list btn--1960">1960s</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn--list btn--1970">1970s</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn--list btn--1980">1980s</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn--list btn--1990">1990s</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn--list btn--2000">2000s</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn--list btn--2010">2010s</button>
  </li>

  <li>
    <h2>Position</h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn--list btn--goalie">Goalie</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn--list btn--defencemen">Defenceman</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn--list btn--forward">Forward</button>
  </li>

  <li>
    <h2>Other</h2>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn--list btn--name">First Name</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn--list btn--hometown">Hometown</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn--list btn--gamesp">Games Played</button>
  </li>
  <li class="not--goalie not--goals">
    <button class="btn--list btn--goals">Goals</button>
  </li>
  <li class="not--goalie not-assists">
    <button class="btn--list btn--assists">Assists</button>
  </li>
  <li class="not--goalie not-points">
    <button class="btn--list btn--points">Points</button>
  </li>
  <li class="not--goalie not-penalty">
    <button class="btn--list btn--penalty">Penalty Minutes</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn--list btn--goalsagainst">Goals Against <span class="is-highlighted">*</span>
    </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn--list btn--savepercent">Save Percentage <span class="is-highlighted">*</span>
    </button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="btn--list btn--shutouts">Shutouts <span class="is-highlighted">*</span>
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```